# Stefan-Boltzmann law - an unclear step in the derivation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermal-radiation

The relevant part from the [wiki derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law):

[image]

I fail to understand why does the "Lambert's cosine law" come in, is it an experimental fact or a mathematical result? I tried to read about this "law" but I still can't understand why it is used here. Also, it might be connected, but why is the integration only on half a sphere?

Comment: The site standard for Mathematics in questions is [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Members are expected to quote text and maths using text and Mathjax, not images.  Images cannot be usefully searched by the site software for content.  Question that post images of text and equations are very actively discouraged, so please use text and Mathjax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A black-body emits radiation from its surface, which is described by the Stefan–Boltzmann law. If you consider a surface section of a black-body, it can only emit radiation with angles between $\theta=-\pi/2$ and $\theta=+\pi/2$ with respect to the surface normal. That's why the integration is only at a hemisphere (corresponds to forward direction). Because, below the hemisphere (backward direction), it becomes absorption, not emission. And between the angles of radiation in the hemisphere, you need to consider only the forward component of them. Because at $\theta=\pm \pi/2$, the radiation becomes zero. Forward component is given by cosine, from trigonometry. See below figure for a visualization.

[image]